# How to get the series from the generating function?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I am trying to solve this problem, where I am given a recurrence relation, for which I need to find all solutions.

The recurrence relation is as follows:
$a_n - 2na_{n-1} + n(n-1)a_{n-2} = 2nn!$, with initial conditions $a_0$ and $a_1$ = 1, and $n \geq 2$.

Using exponential generating functions, I have concluded that the generating function $A(x)$ of this recurrence relation, where $$A(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n \dfrac{x^n}{n!},$$ is given by $$A(x) = \dfrac{2x-3x(1-x)^2 + (1-x)^2}{(1-x)^4}$$.

How would I continue? I cannot see a way to transform this formula into something I can recognize? Normally when I reach this point I try to transform my function into something like one of [these](https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/zju/math/img/gen-func.png), from which I can then find my series.

Comment: You want to expand $(1-x)^{-4}$ and $(1-x)^{-2}$ as their power series, and use linearity to put these together into one big series.

Comment: I mean if I expand the fraction above, I would get $$\dfrac{2x}{(1-x)^4} + \dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2} + \dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$ I know the last two terms are the series $n$ and $1$ respectively, but what about the first one.

Comment: If you differentiate the series for $(1-x)^{-2}$ twice you get $6$ times the series for $(1-x)^{-4}$, then collect with the $2x$ term.

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, I think the last two terms are the $n$ and $(n+1)$ series respectively (basically $x+2x^2+3x^3...$ and $1+2x+3x^2...$). Am I wrong to approach this by dividing the first term $$\dfrac{2x}{(1-x)^4} = \dfrac{2}{(1-x)^2} \cdot \dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$ and expressing this as the product of the two seriest mentioned above?

Comment: you can do this but multiplying out the series will be tougher than taking the term by term differentiation approach. Also feel free to compute the taylor series of $(1-x)^{-4}$ or look up its power series

Comment: correct about expansion of $(1-x)^{-2} $and $x(1-x)^{-2}$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst this is the part that gets me most confused. Intuitively, I am looking for  a closed formula of series $a_{n}$ as a function of $n$ (one that will obviously satisfy $a_0 = a_1 = 1$). Now since I know the generating function, if I can represent/express it in a pretty way then I know the series...
It gets me confused as to why I can get the derivative of a function. Even if I do, do I not have to integrate later to come back to what I started with?

Comment: From the generalized binomial theorem, $(1-x)^{-s} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s-k-1}{k} x^k$.

Comment: @martycohen but what about the $2x$?

Comment: It just increases the power of x by 1.

Comment: That should be$(1-x)^{-s} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{k} x^k$.

Comment: Well since in this case $s=4$ I then got, $\sum_{k\geq 0} {{k+3} \choose k} x^k$, which after multiplying by $x$ becomes $\sum_{k\geq 0} {{k+3} \choose k} x^{k+1}$ (disregarding the $2$ for a second). Adjusting that I got $\sum_{k\geq 1} {{k+2} \choose {k-1}} x^{k}$, to which I can re-add the 0-th term (because it will be 0), to finally get $\sum_{k\geq 0} {{k+2} \choose {k-1}} x^{k}$, which in turn means that my series is $a_k = 2{{k+2} \choose {k-1}}$. Is this correct? Somehow it doesn't obey the recurrence relation.

Comment: Note that $\binom{k+2}{k-1}=\binom{k+2}{3}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would expand
your expression.

I'll use

$\begin{array}\\
(1-x)^{-s} 
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{k} x^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{s-1} x^k\\
\text{so}\\
(1-x)^{-2} 
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{s-1} x^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{1+k}{1} x^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1) x^k\\
\text{and}\\
(1-x)^{-4} 
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{s-1} x^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{3+k}{3} x^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(k+3)(k+2)(k+1)}{6} x^k\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
A(x) 
&= \dfrac{2x-3x(1-x)^2 + (1-x)^2}{(1-x)^4}\\
&= \dfrac{2x}{(1-x)^4}-3\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2}\\
&= (2x)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(k+3)(k+2)(k+1)}{6} x^k-3x\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1) x^k+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1) x^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{2(k+3)(k+2)(k+1)}{6} x^{k+1}-3\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1) x^{k+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1) x^k\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(k+2)(k+1)k}{3} x^{k}-3\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kx^k+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1) x^k\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left( \dfrac{(k+2)(k+1)k}{3} -3k+(k+1)\right) x^k+1\\
&=1+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left( \dfrac{3(-2k+1)+k^3+3k^2+2k}{3}\right) x^k\\
&=1+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left( \dfrac{k^3+3k^2-4k+3}{3}\right) x^k\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Looks like A(x) was changed. Same deal, different coefficients. I might work on it. Feel free to edit if you want.

Comment: I fixed it and got what you got.